# image scrolling in Pinch Zoom in windows phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I designed an app and i put the functionality of pinch zoom in images for windows phone 8. Image is zooming with pinch zoom but it is not scrolling. It is fixed. user can't scroll image after making the image zoom to see the image properly.

I tried to put scroll viewer with image but in that case image is scrolling but not zooming.
pls inform me how i can scroll the image after making it zoom in windows phone 8.

Answer (score 0):

This sample of code shows how to implement a smooth pinch and zoom experience for an image. This scenario demonstrates how to implement a smooth zooming experience using a ViewPort control and the PinchManipulation property of the OnManipulationDelta event on the ViewPort. It shows how to zoom the image around the central point of the pinch, an action that is familiar to users from when they pinch and zoom on a map on the phone. http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Image-Recipes-0c0b8fee